# NoReverseMatch at /reset-password/... in Django

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm new to Django; I get this error when I want to reset a user's password by using a code that is set to account in DB.

**`views.py`**

```py
class ResetPassword(View):
    def get(self, request, active_code):
        user : User = User.objects.filter(email_active_code__iexact=active_code).first()
        if User is None:
            return redirect(reverse('login-page'))
        else:
            reset_password_form = ResetPasswordForm()
            context={
                'reset_password_form' : reset_password_form,
                'title': 'Reset My Password'
            }
            return render(request, 'account_module/reset_password.html', context)
```

related `path` in **`urls.py`**

```py
path('reset-password/<str:active_code>', views.ResetPassword.as_view(), name='reset_password')
```

related form in **templates**

```html
<form action="{% url "reset_password" %}">
                            {% csrf_token %}
                            {{ reset_password_form.label_tag }}
                            {{ reset_password_form }}
                            {{ reset_password_form.errors }}
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Reset My Password</button>
                        </form>
```

The active code that is set:

[image: database info]

[image]

[image: in template]

[image: in Run]

Would someone please take a look and help? Thank you.

Comment: The error message should be clear. You reference with `{% url "reset_password" %}` to an URL that does expect an `active_code`. But you don't provide it.

Answer (score 0):

The [`NoReverseMatch`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/exceptions/#noreversematch) error is saying that Django cannot find a matching URL

Based on what you posted and with help of images, it seems the issue is related to passing `active_code` argument as your url parameter with it in the below form tag:

```html
<form action="{% url "reset_password" %}">
```

So you should change it to something like below tag:

```html
<form action={% url 'reset_password' active_code=active_code %}>
```